# POSTing value from Angular to MVC controller results in null value

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to pass a value from angular to my MVC Core controller to use in a repository function as simple string. However, I've noticed that it's passing a null value to the MVC controller. I don't want to create an MVC model just to use the POSTed JSON as a string.

#### Function excerpt from MVC controller

```
[HttpPost("api/specials/GetCurrentSpecialsBySiteID")]
public ActionResult GetCurrentSpecials([FromBody] string siteID)
{
    return Ok(_repo.GetAllSpecialsBySiteID(siteID));
}
```

#### $Http Angular function

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/specials/GetCurrentSpecialsBySiteID',
        data: siteID,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log(response);
            vm.Specials.push(response.data);
            angular.copy(response.data, vm.Specials);
            console.log(vm.Specials);
            // clear the form 
            vm.newSpecials = {};
        }, function (response) {
           // failure
            console.log("Error !" + response.data);
            vm.errorMessage = "Failed to save subscription";
        })
        .finally(function () {
            vm.isBusy = false;
        });
```

Comment: What is `siteID` in your `$http()`?

Comment: seems you are passing data using "application/json" so i guess "siteID" should be in json format ..
"{'siteID' : 10}"
may be this is creating problem

Comment: Why are you posting this? It looks like you might be better off performing a GET rather than a POST.

Answer (score 0):

In mvc controller you are passing action parameter as string.
Please check you "siteID" Type in your JS.

method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/specials/GetCurrentSpecialsBySiteID',
        data: **siteID**,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }
        })

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like you should probably be performing a GET rather than a POST, however you can adapt your methods as follows to get up and running:

```
[HttpPost("api/specials/GetCurrentSpecialsBySiteID")]
public ActionResult GetCurrentSpecials([FromUri] string siteID)
{
    return Ok(_repo.GetAllSpecialsBySiteID(siteID));
}
```

And your angular function:

```
$http.post('/api/organisations/test?siteID=' + siteID)
     .then(function (response) {
         ...
     })
     .finally(function () {
         ...
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass object in $Http Angular function.

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/specials/GetCurrentSpecialsBySiteID',
        data: {siteID: siteID},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' }
        })
        .then....
```

For more just check $http service documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).